# ways to use a written library locally

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, leiningen

Unitl now, I know two ways to include my written libraries to a clojure project:

- **Symlink** the library file to the src dictionary of my current project, then just require the ns, that is declared in the lib.
- Making the library public via **Clojars**, then adding it to the lein dependencies of my current project. (and require the ns)

Is there a way in between? Say, I have developed something, that I don't want to publish yet, but I want to be able to easily require it in my repls and projects.

Comment: What is wrong with your symlink approach?

Comment: Well, it's not wrong, but I'm looking for something easier. Say, I'm working on a library, it's almost done, but maybe not really tested. I just want to be able to require the lib "by one line" in any repl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way to do this is to run `lein install` in the lib, then require it as you would any other dependency using name and version in your project file.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Just tried it - works. Could I also require the lib in any repl?

Comment: You would need to add the jar to the classpath - there is the lib pomegranate that makes this possible at runtime (or alembic if you want more lein integration for runtime loading).